# Создание общей папки

Tags: windows, lan

Так я создал из моего компютера сеть беспроводной и 3 компютера подключены.Теперь я хочу создать папку такую чтобы в всех 4-ех компютерах была public и все 4 компютеры могли туда что то кидать или взять т.д как сделать помогите?

Comment: Ну а в обзоре сети ничего нету что ли?

Comment: Вопрос не понял очень. Я создал сеть компютер-компютер и в проводнике/Сеть есть подключенные 3

Comment: Ресурс "Общие документы" отвечает всем заявленным требованиям. Он имеется на каждом компьютере, где установлена и активна служба доступа к файлам и принтерам, если не был удалён/перекрыт сознательно.